# Do enchanting requirements change in the Nether?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I had a level 30 enchantment table setup in the Overworld, but made a blaze xp/rod grinder and moved the entire enchant table and bookshelves to the Nether to enchant there. I was about to enchant a pickaxe, when I saw that the enchantment table was only able to go up to level 20. I checked the bookshelves, and while I do not have the required 16, I have 15, which should get me up to 28.

Do enchanting requirements change in the Nether?

Comment: Are you sure nothing is blocking the bookshelves? There should be nothing between the enchanting table and the bookshelves including things like torches or carpets.

Comment: The structure and space around the bookshelves is as important as the number.

Comment: If the answer helped you, you can mark it as accepted using the checkmark icon. If it didn't help you, please specify why.

Answer (score 2):

No. The enchantment requirements stay the same for both the Overworld and the Nether. I did a little testing and the results can be viewed [here](https://youtu.be/qMtOncoc3b0). I gave myself 150 levels of XP, then created an enchantment station with some bookshelves in each dimension. Both stations in the Overworld and Nether provided level 30 enchantments.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but your video doesn't show it really, because you generated a set of enchantments in the Nether, then just saw the same set in the Overworld. You didn't generate a new set of enchantments in the Overworld. It would be theoretically possible to differ still, despite looking like that in your video. But it doesn't.